# Java script date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, web

Does the date object get the values from the operating system locally ? what if someone changes his time value , in my project I need to implement a system for reserving food, in my case the user can't make request for food before 10 am , but what if one of the users change his current time ? 
I think that the best choice is to get time value form backed side.
any suggestions ?

Comment: your server side script should validate the reservation time. **Don't rely on browser side validations**

Comment: Please edit your title to actually describe your issue. And correct spelling of JavaScript to avoid collision with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you do in javascript is client side, it's executed in the browser of the user, so your date object will be created depending on the client's browser.

Moreover, all the validation about the time has to be server side to prevent any kind of alteration. You have to perform ajax requests and make sure on your server that the client is allowed to buy food.